# "Loop" SQL db from column ranges // Snowflake

Tags: sql, loops, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

could you help me solve my problem, please?

I have **table** like:

[image: tables]

```
name  from   to
x001  1      4
x002  9      12  
x003  14     15
```

And I want to **"loop"** with numbers between **from** and **to** column and meanwhile **keep** name index with x00

like this result:

```
name      number    
x001      1    
x001      2    
x001      3
x001      4
x002      9
x002      10
x002      11
x002      12
x003      14
x003      15
```

I use **snowflake**.

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVtc8.png)

BIG thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two steps are to make a range of data via GENERATOR which requires a fixed input, and then to make a sequence of number which SEQ4 can have gaps so that needs to be feed into a ROW_NUMBER to make sure there are no gaps.

Then you can join to the data range.

```
WITH gen AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SEQ4()) as rn
    FROM TABLE(generator(rowcount => 1000))
)
SELECT a.name
    ,b.rn as number 
FROM table AS a
JOIN gen AS b 
    ON b.rn BETWEEN a.from AND a.to
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     Select * from (Select name, "from" + row_number() over 
     (order by 1)  fr
     From 
     Table) t 
     Where 
     t.fr>( 
     Select rn from (
     Select row_number() over (order by 1) rn 
     From
     <some_big_table_with_counts=max(to)>
     ) 
     Where rn<=t.to)
```